# How to map interface with multi-inheritance?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have following original class structure:

```
public interface IMapFromElement
{
    string Prop { get; }
}

public interface IMapFromElementDerived : IMapFromElement
{
    string Prop2 { get; }
}

public interface IMapFromElement2 : IMapFromElement
{
}

public interface IMapFromElementDerived2 : IMapFromElementDerived, IMapFromElement2
{
}

public abstract class MapFromElement : IMapFromElement2
{
    public string Prop { get; set; }
}


public class MapFromElementDerived : MapFromElement, IMapFromElementDerived2
{
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to map them to:

```
public class MapTo
{
    public IMapToElementWritable Element { get; set; }
}

public interface IMapToElementWritable : IMapFromElement
{
    new string Prop { get; set; }
}

public interface IMapToElementWritableDerived : IMapFromElementDerived, IMapToElementWritable
{
    new string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public abstract class MapToElement : IMapToElementWritable
{
    public string Prop { get; set; }
}

public class MapToElementDerived : MapToElement, IMapToElementWritableDerived
{
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

I try to map them with:

```
var from = new MapFrom
{
    Element = new MapFromElementDerived {Prop = "qwerty", Prop2 = "asdf"}
};
Mapper.Initialize(
    cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<IMapFrom, MapTo>();
        cfg.CreateMap<IMapFromElement, IMapToElementWritable>();

        cfg.CreateMap<IMapFromElementDerived, IMapToElementWritableDerived>()
            .IncludeBase<IMapFromElement, IMapToElementWritable>()
            .ConstructUsing((ResolutionContext item) => new MapToElementDerived());

        cfg.Seal();
    });
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

var result = Mapper.Map<MapTo>(from);
```

I expected, that I will have as output MapTo with MapToElementDerived as it's Element property value. But really I was unable to achieve it - Automapper creates proxy for IMapToElementWritable instead. Looks like IncludeBase doesn't work (I tried it with Include also, but it haven't helped). Maybe I just write incorrect config.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an issue in Automapper. I've tried to resolve it in https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/pull/1037